Coding to convert Date from Worksheet to Textbox
I have my dates in worksheet but its appear format as number in textbox, and I'd like to convert them to dates in textbox. Whats code do I input to my userform?
Private Sub TBMOS_Change()
    Me.TBMOS.value = Format(CDate(TBMOS.value), "DD/MM/YYYY")
    Exit Sub
End Sub

I've input this code but there is error Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

How do you fill the textbox?

Date values are numeric, so leave that. What you need is to apply a date format to those cells.

The question asked in comments, how do you fill the textbox, needs an answer to give you a solution. Try this
Private Sub TBMOS_Change()
    If IsDate(TBMOS.Value) Then
        Me.TBMOS.Value = Format(CDate(TBMOS.Value), "DD/MM/YYYY")
    End If
End Sub

It might work for you need, but not if you type the dates manually. If that's the case, it will get more complicated. Either wait for the lost focus event or add an delay.
